# how to change icons and set attributes in Carousel react-bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, carousel, react-bootstrap

I am using Carousel in react-bootstrap, but I didn`t figure out how to change things in this Carousel. For instance, I want change glyphicon icon and stop autoplay, but no success. Do u know how to set attributes and icon?

```
import React, {  Component } from 'react';
import {Carousel} from 'react-bootstrap';


class CarouselMain extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            prevIcon: '<Glyphicon glyph="chevron-up" />'
        }
    }

    handleSelect = (selectedIndex, e) => {
        this.setState({
            index: selectedIndex,
            direction: e.direction
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Carousel autoPlay={false} onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img width={900} height={500} alt='900x500' src='/assets/carousel.png'/>
                    <Carousel.Caption>
                        <h3>First slide label</h3>

                         <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img width={900} height={500} alt='900x500' src='/assets/carousel.png'/>
                    <Carousel.Caption>
                        <h3>Second slide label</h3>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img width={900} height={500} alt='900x500' src='/assets/carousel.png'/>
                    <Carousel.Caption>
                        <h3>Third slide label</h3>

                        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
            </Carousel>
        )
    }
}

export default CarouselMain;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Controlled Carousel:

Actually here you are not controlling the carousel.
to control the carousel you have to send 'direction' and 'index' as props. Check the link: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#carousels-controlled

2. Changing Icons

You can change the navigation icons by your predefined icons by passing 'nextIcon' and 'prevIcon' props.  Check the props list which you can pass it to the component in the mentioned link

```js
import React, {  Component } from 'react';
import {Carousel} from 'react-bootstrap';


class CarouselMain extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            index: 1,  //index which u want to display first
            direction: null //direction of the carousel..u need to set it to either 'next' or 'prev' based on user click
            nextIcon: <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-glass"></span>,
            prevIcon: <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-glass"></span>
        }
    }

    handleSelect = (selectedIndex, e) => {
        this.setState({
            index: selectedIndex,
            direction: e.direction
        });
    }

    render() {
        const {nextIcon,prevIcon}=this.state;
        return (
            <Carousel nextIcon ={nextIcon} prevIcon={prevIcon}  index={this.state.index} direction={this.state.direction} onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img width={900} height={500} alt='900x500' src='/assets/carousel.png'/>
                    <Carousel.Caption>
                        <h3>First slide label</h3>
                         <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img width={900} height={500} alt='900x500' src='/assets/carousel.png'/>
                    <Carousel.Caption>
                        <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img width={900} height={500} alt='900x500' src='/assets/carousel.png'/>
                    <Carousel.Caption>
                        <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
            </Carousel>
        )
    }
}
export default CarouselMain;
```

Comment: could u pls show me i n code version. How u would write that?

Comment: const nextIcon = { <span>X</span>} //your own next icon
  const prevIcon = { <span>O</span>} // your own prev icon - these two spans throw the errors. I guess not right syntax